# Amazon S3: BeginUpload() vs new thread with Upload()

Tags: .net, amazon-s3

I'm working with the Amazon S3 Transfer Utility (for .Net).  Currently, I am using the .BeginUpload() function to create an asynchronous thread to upload the file while my main thread continues processing.

I'm running into a problem, however, where the TransferUtility will occasionally throw an error, cancelling the upload.  It also seems that the thread will occasionally abort completely (without any log4net exceptions logged).

Because of this, I'm reconsidering the method I'm using for making the upload asynchronous.  I see two options:

- BeginUpload(), get the IAsyncResult, start a new thread that immediately calls .EndUpload(result)
- Spawn a new thread that calls the .Upload directly (instead of .BeginUpload()).

**My question:**

If I started a new thread to upload the queue, would that work in the same way as the .BeginUpload()/.EndUpload() calls?

In other words this:

```
IAsyncResult ar = myTransferUtility.BeginUpload(uploadRequest);
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c => {
    try
    {
        myTransferUtility.EndUpload(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        handleException(ex, "Asynch Uploading");
    }
});
```

versus

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(c => {
    try
    {
        myTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        handleException(ex, "Asynch Uploading");
    }
});
```

What's the difference?

(There is a an UploadCompleted callback that doesn't always get called when these rare exceptions/aborts occur.  This callback is what I want to guarantee happens.  It would be in the "catch".)